# calculate unknown source potential

Tags: source

In order to prepare for an exam in electro technics I have a specific task:
I have the following measurements of an unknown circuit:

\$(1)\quad U_{2(1)} = 4.28V \quad @ I_{(1)}=0.67A \$

\$(2)\quad U_{2(2)} = 1.38V \quad @ I_{(1)}=4.91A \$

Now I have to calculate the internal resistance.
The formula therefor is either \$ R_i = \dfrac{\Delta U}{\Delta I}\$ or \$R_i = \dfrac{U_s}{I_c}\$

where \$U_s\$ is the source potential and \$I_c\$ the short-circuit current.

I don't want to use the delta formula because I need the other two values in a later task anyway.

How do I calculate the source potential just having the both values?

Comment: It is unclear to me what \$U_{2(2)}\$, \$U_{2(2)}\$ and \$I_{(1)}\$ means in this context. Can you add a circuit diagram or at very least eleborate on this?

Comment: Well there is no circuit diagram given. the number in brackets refers to the first and second measurement, sorry I should have written this. edit done.

Comment: I also think that the task means that the measurements are taken from the same position within the circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to use the delta formula ...

That's unfortunate because that's the formula to use.

\${{4.28\text{V}-1.38\text{V}}\over{4.91\text{A}-0.67\text{A}}} \approx 684 \text{m}\Omega\$

\$4.28\text{V}+0.67\text{A}\cdot684\text{m}\Omega\approx4.74 V\$

\$1.38\text{V}+4.91\text{A}\cdot684\text{m}\Omega\approx4.74 V\$

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've found another way to calculate the source potential as well as the short-circuit current before calculating the internal resistance, but your way is obviously more nice than the one I explored.